# Scrapy ImagesPipeline WARNING: File (unknown-error): Error downloading image from <GET

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am learning Python and Scrapy and I am learning how to download images using it. I am kind of stuck right now and I cant figure out what the real problem is.

I am getting this error message when I run the spider

```
<None>: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme
```

and

```
[imageflip] WARNING: File (unknown-error): Error downloading image from <GET
```

Please see my pipelines.py here

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


class PriceoflipkartPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
    if not image_paths:
        raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
    item['image_paths'] = image_paths
    return item
```

Please see my settings.py here

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['PriceoFlipkart.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'PriceoFlipkart.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline']
IMAGES_STORE = 'D:\PriceoFlipkart\Images'
IMAGES_EXPIRES = 90
```

Please see my Spider here

```
import scrapy
from PriceoFlipkart.items import PriceoflipkartItem

class FlipkartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imageflip"
    allowed_domains = ["flipkart.com"]
     start_urls = [
    "http://www.flipkart.com/moto-g-2nd-gen/p/itme5z8n9mt77ajr?pid=MOBDYGZ6SHNB7RFC&srno=b_1&ref=06f4e48c-9548-45fa-b3ac-fa5fdf0e0d22"
]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//body'):
        item = PriceoflipkartItem()
        item['image_urls'] = sel.select('//img[@class="productImage  current"]').extract()
        yield item
```

and in my item.py I have added the following code

```
image_urls = scrapy.Field()
images = scrapy.Field()
```

Please advice me as to how to configure it correctly so that the image is downloaded. I am on a Windows 8 machine. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath to extract image URLs is not correct, it should include `/@src` at the end to extract only the URL for the image. Make it like:

```
item['image_urls'] = sel.select(
    '//img[@class="productImage  current"]/@src').extract()
```

Comment: Good finding! Thanks.

Comment: Great! Thanks. It worked. I could download the image.